# django- why persian texts not display properly?

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates

i worked on a django project.
now i deployed the project on real physical server.but there is a problem.in the production, site does not display persian texts that saved in Database(MySQL) properly, while in my laptop (localhost) it displays persian texts without any problem.

[image]

as you see, other texts(that are not from the database) was displayed correct, but those texts that are from the database, was displayed ????????? .
what's the problem and how to solve it?
tanx.

Comment: Can you tell us about the table in mysql? Which version? What happens when you select the columns in that table with an sql client?

Comment: @shawnMehan hi...collation of all tables of database is "latin1_swedish_ci".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your charset in MySQL. Default is Latin.